# Reset an iframe before navigation

Tags: browser, iframe

I have a parent page and an iframe. When the user clicks on a link on the parent, it loads up in iframe. But the content in iframe doesn't change immediately when you click the link. The old content remains for few seconds until a network request is initiated, and then DOM is wiped up and repopulated with the new content.

What I need is, as soon as the user clicks the link, DOM is wiped off and then content is loaded. I don't want the user to see the old page even for few seconds after the link is clicked.

Comment: I kind of got it working by iframeObj.contentWindow.document.write('')

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in a hackyway

`iframeObj.contentWindow.document.write('')`